# PHP anonymous functions: how to pass $this and write a fallback?

Tags: php, oop, anonymous-function

`$this` is not supported for anonymous functions inside a class for php5.3.x, how do I get around to this so I can pass the `$this` info/ data to the anonymous function? How can I write a fallback to php5.3.x?

```
class anonymous {

    protected $methods = array();

    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        $this->methods = $options;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $callable = null;
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->methods))
            $callable = $this->methods[$name];
        elseif(isset($this->$name))
            $callable = $this->$name;

        if (!is_callable($callable))
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$name} does not exists");

        return call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments);
    }
}

class myclass {

    private $options = array();

    public function __construct($options = array()){
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    public function hello($data = null, $options = array()){

        $methods = new anonymous(array(
            "init" => function($options) { 

                echo "init";

                if(!$options) $options = $this->options;

                return $options; 
            }, 

            "run" => function($options) { 
                echo "run";
                return $options; 
            } 
        ));

        $default = array(
            "method" => "init",
            "options" => array()
        );

        if($data === null) {
            $method = "init";
        } else if (is_string($data)) { 
            $method = $data;
        } else if(is_array($data)) {
            $method = "init";
            $options = $data;
        }

        // Return the requested method.
        return $methods->$method($options);

    }

}
```

so for,

```
$myclass = new myclass(array("hello world!"));
var_dump($myclass->hello());
```

result,

> init
>       Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/content/95/10799595/html/bin/test/anonymous_4.php on line 41 -->
>   if(!$options) $options = $this->options;

I should be getting this as in my localhost which is on php5.4,

> init array (size=1)   0 => string 'hello world!' (length=12)

Any solutions and suggestions?

**EDIT:**

```
public function hello($data = null, $options = array()){

        $self = $this;

        $methods = new anonymous(array(
            "init" => function($options) use($self){ 

                echo "init";

                if(!$options) $options = $self->options;

                return $options; 
            }, 

            "run" => function($options) { 
                echo "run";
                return $options; 
            } 
        ));

        $default = array(
            "method" => "init",
            "options" => array()
        );

        if($data === null) {
            $method = "init";
        } else if (is_string($data)) { 
            $method = $data;
        } else if(is_array($data)) {
            $method = "init";
            $options = $data;
        }

        // Return the requested method.
        return $methods->$method($options);

    }
```

still get an error.

> Fatal error: Cannot access private property myclass::$options in
>   /home/content/95/10799595/html/bin/test/anonymous_4.php on line 43

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
$foobar = $this;

$anonymous = function() use($foobar) {

};
```

works.

It’s silly, but that’s php... :)

Comment: thanks. i tried it but still get an error. please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: You’d need to tell what row that is 43 is. FWIW, I don’t really understand what you’re trying to achieve in first place, this seems too complicated. Might be wise to see whether simple anonymous function instead of that kind of thingy would work better :)

Comment: Just make a public getOptions method.  You can't access anything private directly through `$self`.